Firebase Cloud Function Email Body Shows Only "{}" Despite Sending Form Data
I'm working on a firebase cloud Function to send form submissions via email using Nodemailer. I'm currently testing this using the Firebase Emulator. The issue I'm facing is that the email body only contains "{}" instead of the form details.
Here is how I have the function setup:
import * as functions from 'firebase-functions';
import nodemailer from 'nodemailer';
import cors from 'cors';
import * as dotenv from 'dotenv';

dotenv.config();

const corsHandler = cors({ origin: true });

const emailUser = process.env.EMAIL_USER || functions.config().email.user;
const emailPass = process.env.EMAIL_PASS || functions.config().email.pass;

const transporter = nodemailer.createTransport({
  service: 'gmail',
  auth: {
    user: emailUser,
    pass: emailPass,
  },
});

export const sendMail = functions.https.onRequest((req, res) => {
  corsHandler(req, res, async () => {
    try {
      const formData = req.body;
      console.log('Form Data (raw):', req.body);

      // Checking if formData is correctly parsed
      const parsedData = typeof formData === 'string' ? JSON.parse(formData) : formData;
      console.log('Parsed Form Data:', parsedData);

      const mailOptions = {
        from: emailUser,
        to: 'my@email.co',
        subject: 'Form Submission',
        text: `Here are the details of your submission:\n\n${JSON.stringify(parsedData, null, 2)}`,
      };

      console.log('Mail Options:', mailOptions);

      const info = await transporter.sendMail(mailOptions);
      console.log('Email sent:', info.response);

      res.status(200).send({ message: 'Email sent successfully!' });
    } catch (error) {
      console.error('Error sending email:', error);
      res.status(500).send({ error: `An error occurred while trying to send the email: ${(error as Error).message}` });
    }
  });
});

I am passing this through Postman as a POST request with this as the json body:
{
  "firstName": "John",
  "lastName": "Doe",
  "email": "johndoe@example.com",
  "phone": "1234567890",
  "vehicleType": "single",
  "carLoan": "Yes",
  "loanAmount": "20000",
  "vin": "1HGCM82633A123456",
  "miles": "5000",
  "amount": "15000"
}

This is the output in my terminal for the firebase function:
i  functions: Loaded environment variables from .env.
⚠  functions: The Cloud Firestore emulator is not running, so calls to Firestore will affect production.
i  functions: Beginning execution of "us-central1-sendMail"
>  Form Data (raw): {}
>  Parsed Form Data: {}
>  Mail Options: {
>    from: 'my@email.co',
>    to: 'my@email.co',
>    subject: 'Form Submission',
>    text: 'Here are the details of your submission:\n\n{}'
>  }
>  Email sent: 250 2.0.0 OK  1720646343 af79cd13be357-79f190b7a60sm226610185a.134 - gsmtp
i  functions: Finished "us-central1-sendMail" in 1617.698875ms

I can verify that email is being sent, but the email only contains "{}" as stated above, instead of the form details.
Please help me stack overflow gods!
What Ive Tried

Ensuring the Content-Type header is set to application/json in the frontend.
Parsing the request body in the Firebase function.
Logging the request body in the Firebase function.

What I'm expecting
The email body should contain the details of the form submission in JSON format.
Current Results
The email body only contains {}, and the logs show that the parsed form data is {}.
Any help or guidance on how to resolve this issue would be greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance!

Can you add a log of req.rawBody into your question? It should be a raw buffer containing the data sent to your function. This will help target where the problem may lie.

If the frontend code isn't part of your testing process that gives the unexpected result, then just remove it from the question to avoid confusing things.  If the problem happens only when you use postman, then your question should contain only the information necessary to reproduce the problem with postman.  Showing the JSON might not be enough here to reproduce exactly what you're doing.

@samthecodingman Thanks for the response.
Logged it and here is the output. Let me know if this helps or if I can clarify anything else.
Logged it as such:
const formData = req.body;
console.log('Raw Body:', req.rawBody);
Heres what was returned:
Raw Body: <Buffer >
What's the purpose of logging this?

@DougStevenson To clarify, I am more concerned with testing the Firebase function using Postman, and the frontend code isn't so much as relevant in this testing process. I'm having this issue when I send a POST request via Postman. If I can provide more context, please let me know.

So if the frontend code you show here isn't relevant, I'm suggesting that you edit the question to remove it so others won't be confused about the source of the problem and how to reproduce it.

@DougStevenson Removed it, apologies first SO question

@SethStitick If its logging <Buffer >, that's indicating there may be a problem with what data is being sent to your server because you would expect <Buffer 7b 7d> to be logged if the body of your request was actually fed an empty object JSON string like "{}".
